# images become blurry after resizing ? gimp ebay

Tags: gimp, resize, image-quality, visual-artifacts

For ebay shop I've created this image:
[image]

You can see that the image is perfect. but the problem that after I upload it to ebay. the quality is changed, and the picture become pixelated, as you can see here:

[image: http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/images/m/mkeBJJBYWQR532FrHgEkuug/s-l225.jpg]

& here

[image: http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/pict/2525094841246464_1.jpg]

Why this happening? should I do something to make the image resizable?

[Here is my gimp file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw8vnOWKrLfgbEFaYll6TXVBNU0) and here are my export options:

[image]

Comment: If the quality is only changing *after* uploading to ebay, the problem is with ebay—not much anyone can do about that (for what it's worth the ebay thumbs look fine to me, just normal jpg compression and resizing—which is the whole point of making thumbnails)

Comment: thank you for your response. i've contacted ebay and they told me that the problem with my image quality.as you can see the problem is next to the small 4 images there is black line of points, which make the image looks unprofessional !!!

Comment: I don't see any black lines? The problem is 100% ebay's compression/resizing method so in not sure what they expect you to do about it, what exactly did eBay say?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If you are reducing that much the size you should optimize your original space. You have too much white space between glasses. If you can prepare a diferent thumbnail without the color changes.

Probably the best option is to have one clear image for your first photo without the color changes, just the best one, and leave the other for the aditional photos.

**2)** The images lack of contrast on the thin parts, when you resize them they blur even more to white. Contrast them a little more.

**3)** If you can upload diferent images, prepare them.

Apply some sharpen after you resize to the final size. You also can correct a bit the previously mentioned contrast after the resampling.

Comment: You can't upload different images and you can't do anything with the resized images as far as I'm aware

Comment: Ok I separated point 3.

Answer (score 0):

If eBay is converting your upload to some fixed aspect ratio, and you have no control over it. Even if you upload HD image the result will be same. If ebay allows you to set compression ratio, set it to highest quality available.

Comment: I've never known Ebay to change the aspect ratio of an image. I don't think that's the problem. Also, for web images, you don't want a high quality compression because they load slower. But for what it's worth, I doubt that most ebay viewers will even notice the difference. Also, I notice you have a "smoothing" option and a "show preview" option. Why not use those and see if it helps?

Answer (score -2):

you should resize in actual pixel (i.e 64x64 or 225x225) you need for ebay so you can see actual pixel in your software, and you should avoid picture with many detail for thumbnail like that, use one single image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please have a look at this one https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw8vnOWKrLfgQkxkakx6S2ZvZlE there is no black line next to the small images !